# TFS unable to ignore tracked files

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I'm using Eclipse (Spring tool suite to be exact) for a Maven project and the TFS plug-in v14. I'd like to ignore some files which are tracked by TFS, as they'll change between development machines. However, despite adding all files to be ignored to .tfignore, they are still detected as pending changes.

For instance, the following files are present on the project root:

```
.classpath
.project
.springBeans
.tfignore
pom.xml
```

The tfignore file:

```
\.project
\target
\src\main\resources\profiles\DEV
\.tfignore
\.classpath
\.settings
\.springBeans
```

I've also tried adding `\.*`, `.springBeans`. I've tried checking in the tgignore file before any changes as well, all to no avail.

Excluding changes only works temporarily as when switching branches, all changes must be shelved or undone.

When performing the same operation through the Eclipse context menu for TFS (Team > Ignore) the error `"Exclusions could not be added for some items
  Error adding exclusion for C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.3.SR1\VTS\.springBeans  parentPath must not be null"` is shown

For the `\src\main\resources\profiles\DEV`path, I'm able to cloak the folder server side, but am not able to do so with files in the root of the project (this would cloak the entire project). The option to cloak individual files is not listed through TFS.

Is it not possible to ignore files locally from source control once they're added?  I would expect this to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a bit, I've found that tracked files cannot be ignored by Team Explorer Everywhere TFS Eclipse plug-in. The source will need to be cloaked to ignore local changes from being detected under pending changes.

As for files in the root of the project which change based on a developer's environment, these should be removed from source control all together. Initial setup of the environment should produce these derived files (setting this flag in Eclipse also has no effect on tracked files). Once placing these in .tfignore, the plug-in ignores these as expected.